# Windows AutoStart sometimes (randomly?) not working

Tags: c++, qt, registry, autostart, autorun

So i wrote myself a handy application that i always want to run.
It's written in C++ with QT.

Autostart is done trough the registry
If the user clicks the autorun checkbox, this code gets executed

```
QSettings RegSettings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
    QSettings::NativeFormat);
if (ui.cb_autorun->isChecked())
{
    RegSettings.setValue("FanControlV2", "\"" + QDir::currentPath().remove("/platforms").replace("/", "\\") + "\\FanControllerV2.exe\"");
}
else {
    RegSettings.remove("FanControlV2");
}
```

This works fine, at least most of the time
But sometimes the application just won't start, and i have to run it manually

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here, since many many other applications start up just fine everytime...

Any advice?

Edit: problem occurs on win7, 8.1 and 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `currentPath` to determine the location of your application's executable is **always an error**. You should never do that. On most operating systems you have no control whatsoever as to what the working directory of your application is. It can literally be anything. Moreover, outside of OS X the users are free to, likely to, nah, encouraged to set the working folder for your application to their liking, so that the file access dialogs will point to a useful, default location.

Most likely, it succeeds when the working directory of your process happens to be the same as its installation folder when the settings are stored in the registry. But this state is just a happy coincidence, as you yourself have experimentally determined.

You should use `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()` to get the correct path. You should also use `QDir::toNativeSeparators` instead of a hand-rolled replacement.

Your code should look as follows:

```
RegSettings.setValue("FanControlV2", QDir::toNativeSeparators(
                     QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()));
```